# How to avoid when I click on a link and it opens an ads page?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, website, advertisements

When I navigate on several web-sites it happened that I click on links and the browser open an ads page. If I try to click a second time on the same link it opens the right page.

1 - Why it happened?

2 - How can I solve it?

I use standard chrome and firefox

It happened for example with news in [www.telefonino.net](http://www.telefonino.net) (and it opens ads video or another page like ivid......)

Comment: add url for example

Comment: There could be many reasons for this; we need more detail. What is the website, what is the link? Does it happen with every browser? Do you share any plugins which could potentially create this behavior?

Comment: From your symptoms I would think you have a browser add-on or other malware because when you click a link for the first time you get an ad page, but the second click takes you to the right page... ad blocking software may help, but I fear there is a further underlying problem

Comment: Adblock block this ads on www.telefonino.net. So mark this question solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't tell why it happens exactly, but I can offer solutions.

You could use AdBlock Plus (either in [Firefox](https://adblockplus.org/en/firefox) or [Chrome](https://adblockplus.org/en/chrome)), it does a good job.
If you want more control and more protection you could use [NoScript](http://noscript.net/) (only in Firefox), but it could take some time to learn and adjust.